# Can't put bar button on navigation bar

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, xcode6, uinavigationbar

In xCode when I try to add a new item to the navigation bar, the button keeps appearing at the bottom of the view controller like this:
[image]

I have no idea why this is happening, it seems like a bug in xCode. Has anyone experienced this before?

Any suggestions on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and just fixed it by adding a navigation item to my uiviewcontroller and then dropping the bar button on that navigation item.
You get the navigation item from the object library.